# Converting Shape File to RDF document, in Java

Tags: java, rdf, shapefile, converters

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.URI;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.management.AttributeChangeNotification;

import org.apache.jena.datatypes.xsd.XSDDatatype;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Property;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFNode;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.RDFReaderI;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.Statement;
import org.apache.jena.rdf.model.StmtIterator;
import org.apache.jena.riot.Lang;
import org.apache.jena.riot.RDFDataMgr;
import org.apache.jena.riot.system.StreamRDFWriter;
import org.apache.jena.vocabulary.VCARD;
import org.geotools.data.DataStore;
import org.geotools.data.DataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.FeatureSource;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.FileDataStoreFinder;
import org.geotools.data.Query;
import org.geotools.data.ServiceInfo;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureIterator;
import org.geotools.swing.data.JFileDataStoreChooser;
import org.opengis.feature.ComplexAttribute;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.FeatureType;
import org.opengis.filter.Filter;

public class ShpToRdf {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

        File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
        if (file == null) {
            return;
              
        }

        FileDataStore myData = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource source = myData.getFeatureSource();
        SimpleFeatureType schema = source.getSchema();

        Query query = new Query(schema.getTypeName());
        query.setMaxFeatures(100);

       
        Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        String shpURI = "http://www.shp.fake/";

        Resource shapeFile = model.createResource(shpURI);
         
        FeatureCollection<SimpleFeatureType, SimpleFeature> collection = source.getFeatures(query);
        try (FeatureIterator<SimpleFeature> features = collection.features()) {
            while (features.hasNext()) {
                
                SimpleFeature feature = features.next();
                model.setNsPrefix("shp", shpURI);
            
                for (org.opengis.feature.Property attribute : feature.getProperties()) {
                  names.add(attribute.getName().toString());
                  values.add(attribute.getValue().toString());
                   
                }   
             }  

         }
         
         ArrayList<Integer> ids = new ArrayList<Integer>();
         for(int i=0; i<names.size();i++) {
             if (names.get(i).equals("Id")) {
                ids.add(i); 
             }
         }  

         Property features = model.createProperty(shpURI,"features");
         for(int i = 0; i<ids.size();i++) {
             Property id = model.createProperty(shpURI,names.get(ids.get(i)));
                        
             shapeFile = model.createResource(shpURI)
                        .addProperty(features, model.createResource()
                                         .addProperty(id,model.createResource()
                        .addProperty(id, values.get(ids.get(i)))
                        .addProperty(features, "feature1")
                        .addProperty(features, "feature2")
                        .addProperty(features, "feature3")));

          }

          RDFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, Lang.RDFXML);

      } 
                
            
       
}
```

I am trying to create an application that converts Shape File(shp) to RDF.
The problem is that I can get two ArrayLists from the shp. The one has the names of the values (id,name,geometry etc.), and the other has the values.

To create the RDF, I have to match each Id with the matching values(ex. Id =1  has name = road 1, geometry = line etc.)

Could you help me with this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to do this by tweaking the following bit of logic

```
for (org.opengis.feature.Property attribute : feature.getProperties()) {
   names.add(attribute.getName().toString());
   values.add(attribute.getValue().toString());
}
```

Instead of putting them in two lists, you can put them in a list of pairs. This way when you iterate over the list, you know the mapping between the subject and object.

It should look something similar to

```
List<Pair<String, Integer>> contentList = new ArrayList<Pair<String, String>>();

for (org.opengis.feature.Property attribute : feature.getProperties()) {
   Pair<String, Integer> subjectObjectPairs = new Pair<String, String>(attribute.getName().toString(), attribute.getValue().toString());
   contentList.add(subjectObjectPairs);
}
```

I'm not sure what the `ids` ArrayList is for, but you could move that logic into the for loop above to make sure you're *only* getting identifiers.